# Getting undefined action error while I did define it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'action' of undefined
```

My console claims that it occurs because of this line of code:

```
form.action = "/api/projects";
```

But I really don't understand it, because the code above shows that I did defined it. The url "/api/projects" also exists in my router.

This is what I have:

project.js:

```
var form;
form.action = "/api/projects";
form.type = "GET";

post(form)
.done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

misc.js

```
function post(form)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: form.action,
        type: form.method,
        data: $(form).serialize()
    })
    .always(function (response) {
        if (typeof response.status !== 'undefined' && response.status.toString[0] != 2) {
            notify(response.responseText, 'Warning');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: In `var form; form.action = "/api/projects";` `form` is still `undefined`. You need to define it with `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

form is undefined.  you must init this.

```
var form={};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var form;
form.action = "/api/projects";
```

You create variable. It is undefined. You've got an error. All right;

Try

```
var form = {};
```

Comment: Or better: `var form={action:'/api/projects',type:'GET'};` and without the two `form.` lines.

Comment: Is it better, because it has less to compile which makes it also faster?

Comment: Possible defining with properties will be a little bit faster ( in theory ). But no so much to think about it. But code is more cleaner